# Ionic angular firebase traer todos los datos de una coleccion

Tags: firebase, ionic, angular

recurro a su ayuda, por que no se como resolver esto.
esta es la estructura de mi coleccion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito traer los datos: nombre, descripcion y foto de cada uno. 
en mi provedor lo estaba haciendo de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego, estaba llamando a la funcion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a lo maximo que pude llegar fue a conseguir esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero obviamente, al querer mostrar esos datos, no me muestra nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradeceria! ya no se como hacer

Comment: Hola Jacqueline... Veo que tenés tu estructura de firebase como `perdida/{codigo}/{numero}/` y de allí los datos. No te seria más fácil dejar los datos debajo de `codigo` en vez de meterlos más abajo?

Comment: Otra cosa, en vez de poner imagenes de tu código, pon el texto con formato. Así nos facilitas ayudarte y a ti te sale mejor solo copiar y pegar. No tienes que andar cortando y redimensionando imágenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor que podés hacer es arreglar la estructura de tu base de datos para no anidar tanto la información.

---

Pero si tu estructura TIENE que ser así por motivos de fuerza, entonces aquí esta tu solución:

En tu estructura tenés algo así como: `/perdida/{codigo}/{numero}/` y allí esta la data que quieres.

Con tu código actual lo que estás sacando es hasta `codigo`, o sea que tu data está aún debajo de `numero`. Necesitas un `for(key in object)` más.

```
this.afDB.database.ref('perdida').orderByChild('uid').once('value', snapshot => {
    let catData = snapshot.val();
    let temparr = [];
    for (var key in catData) {
      for (var key2 in catData[key]) { // <= for nuevo
        temparr.push(catData[key][key2]) // <= Extrayendo la data
      }
    }
    resolve(temparr);
})
```

Ese `for` nuevo es para entrar un nodo más abajo. Allí está la data que querés.

Por si acaso, [aquí te dejo un StackBlitz funcionando](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3szd2j).

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! la realidad es que el miercoles tengo que entregar una app para la facultad, jamas había usado ionic y firebase, no me había dado cuenta que no esta realizando la estructura adecuada, pero tenia que cambiar demasiadas cosas para arreglar el lió que había hecho y estoy luchando con el mapa!! realmente me salvaste! gracias por tu buena predisposición!

Comment: @Nery, se ve bueno tu código, como sería implementado para firestore? Me salvarías la vida a mi también y te lo agradecería mucho, por favor...

Comment: @Drewkenobi Mejor abre una nueva pregunta y allí detallas lo que necesitas.

Comment: Quise evitar que pareciera una pregunta duplicada, porque la única diferencia era que deseaba saber como implementar lo mismo pero usando firestore en lugar de realtime database... en fin, igual gracias, ya lo he solucionado. Saludos! =)